# useSelector in React container used with flow types

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, flowtype

I come from the plain javascript world and now I have to rewrite a class component with hooks, but I am having some problems with flow, never worked with it.

I have a functional component which I want to rewrite using hooks, but I can't make these selectors work:

```js
type Props = {
  history: Object,
  sets: Array<Object>,
  tArray: Object,
  gu: Object
};

const Page = () => {

  const { tArray} = useSelector<Object>(state => state.t.tArray.map(x => ({
    A: x.A,
    B: x.B,
    C: x.C
    date: x.lastExportDate
      ? dateFormat(new Date(x.lastExportDate), 'm/dd/yyyy')
      : []
  })))

  const { gu } = useSelector(state => state.gu)
  const { sets } = useSelector(state => state.sets.allSets.map(x=> ({
    value: x.setId,
    label: x.name
  })))

  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  )

}


export default HomePage;
```

I don't know how to write the return types of the selectors and the props received by the container.

None of the first two methods of writing the selectors works.

Thank you

Comment: What error are you getting from Flow?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
const { gu } = useSelector(state)
const { sets } = useSelector(state => state.sets.allSets.map(x=> {
  return {
    sets: {
      value: x.setId,
      label: x.name
   }
  }))
```

The return value should hold what construction needs. So the first construction `gu` has nothing to do as state holds the `gu` object itself. And the `sets` object needed for your second construction which was not returning the required object.

---

Basically, what I wanted to say is:

Suppose, we have an object -

```
const obj = { foo: 1 }
```

And now if we want to construct `foo` to get value:

```
const { foo } = obj.foo // wrong
const { foo } = obj // right
```

I hope, this is now clear to you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help but it doesn't work, it says:

Uncaught ReferenceError: state is not defined
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: state is not defined


I don't know where should I define the type for each property (at the beginning of the container/ inside the selector etc)

Comment: the problem is with flow, never used it before and i'm a bit stuck with these types

Comment: this is now another problem. please look at the docs where you can get help.

Comment: @CristinaMarin try `const gu = useSelector(state => state.gu)`

Comment: Nevermind, I gave up trying to use hooks and flow. Continued without flow.Thank you